# Xcode 7 debugger with C project

Tags: xcode, debugging, makefile, xcode7

I have created `External Build System` project to build and test my C executables (at the top of CMake project for ARM cross-compilation). Unfortunately, I am not able to debug my program using breakpoints - Xcode is completely ignoring them. Steps I did so far inside *Scheme*:

- Checked `Debug executable`.
- Checked `Use custom working directory`.
- Added `-g` flag to *Makefile*.